# How to pack a dict into a struct so that I can store it in a file and later unpack it

Tags: python, struct

I have the following code to pack the dictionary into a struct ...

```
>>> this = bytearray(2)    
>>> this[0] = 100   
>>> this[1] = 150  
>>> bool = True    
>>> str = 'new'  
>>> dct = {'bt_arr': this, 'string':str, 'boolean': bool}  
>>> print dct  
{'bt_arr': bytearray(b'd\x96'), 'boolean': True, 'string': 'new'}  
val = struct.pack ('!' + 'B' +'B' + 'B'*3 + '?', dct['bt_arr'][0], dct['bt_arr'][1],dct['string'][0:3], dct['boolean'])                                                                         
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
struct.error: pack requires exactly 6 arguments
```

can you kindly let me know what I'm doing wrong in the above code....

I want to unpack it in a similar fashion....

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `pickle`, `marshall`, `shelve` etc?

Comment: @Dave Webb: thanks for the edit...

Comment: @SpliFF: I was thinking of struct.pack , since I wanted to store this values as an extended attribute of a file which would be used by my C prog. and I thought struct.pack would do that job in that case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to `martineau` and `eumiro` I got this solution, please let me know if there is a better solution

```
val = struct.pack ('!' + 'B' +'B' + 'c'*3 + '?', *(tuple(dct['bt_arr'][0:2])+ tuple(dct['string'][0:3]) + (dct['boolean'],)))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with missing bracket here:

```
dct['bt_arr'[1]
```

**EDIT:**

```
val = struct.pack ('!' + 'B' +'B' + 'B'*3 + '?', dct['bt_arr'][0], dct['bt_arr'][1],dct['string'][0:3], dct['boolean'])
```

This format `'!' + 'B' +'B' + 'B'*3 + '?'` wants to store five elements, that's why the function needs six arguments (format included). You provide it with four only.

**EDIT2:**

```
val = struct.pack('!' + 'B' +'B' + 'B'*3 + '?', *(list(dct['bt_arr']) + list(dct['string'][0:3]) + [dct['boolean']]))
```

Comment: by dct['string'][0:3] I meant to provide 3 arguments, so how to achive that?

Comment: change it to `list(dct['string'][0:3])`

Comment: Even in that case I get this error `val = struct.pack ('!' + 'B' +'B' + 'B'*3 + '?', dct['bt_arr'][0], dct['bt_arr'][1], list(dct['string'][0:3]), dct['boolean'])`  
`struct.error: pack requires exactly 6 arguments`

Comment: @eumiro: Your EDIT2 gives `struct.error: cannot convert argument to integer`.

Comment: @kuurious - so you probably cannot use `B` as a format for all your data.

Comment: Use `'!' + 'B' +'B' + 'c'*3 + '?'` in @eumiro's EDIT2.

Comment: @marinueau: Just out of curiosity, ho will replacing 'c' with 'B' help it out? since both are one byte represntation

Comment: This worked for me, but is this the most elegant solution? `val = struct.pack ('!' + 'B' +'B' + 'c'*3 + '?', *(tuple(dct['bt_arr'][0:2])+ tuple(dct['string'][0:3]) + (dct['boolean'],)))`

Comment: @kuurious - the most elegant solution would be to use JSON or cPickle, marshall or shelve...